# I need an xml parser in android for the following codes

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-xml

```
<TRACKS>
<songs>
-       <song>
             <name>7340027045879.xml</_name> 
             <Downloadable>True</Downloadable> 
             <Streaming>True</Streaming> 
-        <Setting>
                <Price>9.99</Price> 
                <Purcahse_``Id>213213123sadsadsaasdsss</Purcahse_Id> 
-        </Setting>
         </song>
</songs>
<songs>
-        <song>
                <name>7340027045879.xml</_name> 
                <Downloadable>True</Downloadable> 
                <Streaming>True</Streaming> 
-        <Setting>
                <Price>9.99</Price> 
                <Purcahse_Id>213213123sadsadsaasdsss</Purcahse_Id> 
-        </Setting>
         </song>
-<songs>
</tracks>
<social include="True">
               <tag>True</tag> 
               <account>False</feed> 
-       <details>
              <tag>Carola</tag> 
        </details>
</social>
```

I'm new to android so could anyone plz help me to parse this particular xml with an xml parser in android and the source of the xml should be accessed within the folder itself.thank u.:)

Comment: what have you tried, how did it work, how did it fail?   SO is not a location for 'send me the codez'

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking specific coding questions not for asking people to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SAXParser`. You can find a great tutorial [here](http://www.anddev.org/post102961.html?hilit=xml%20parser&sid=ed096d794d1f350b3887752aa6254cd3#p102961). Read it out :D

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) on IBM's developerWorks site. It provides a fairly good overview of the XML parsing options available and some sample code for each option.